# How do I access the elements/objects in this JSON string?

Tags: php, json, decode

I have a very large JSON string (over 1mb). It starts like this:

> [[{"timestamp":1456815458,"total_jobs":6398,"latest_height":99045,"jobs":{"152.62.311.2:123":[8003,"/Main:5.1/",1655659260,1,395047,"ec4.ap-southeast-3.amazonaws.com","Capetown","AU",-317.8815,57.5,"Australia/NSW","AS1511","Amazon.com, Inc."],"183.215.34.58:9805":[56734,"/JobPlace2:0.11.0/",1455767214,1,399047,"185.211.134.58","Seoul","KR",57.5983,126.9783,"Asia/Seoul","AS32665","HCLC"],...

I would like to be able to echo the IP addresses as well as the information attached with the IP address (there's about 13 pieces of sub-information after each IP address).

How do I do this? I have never accessed classes/objects within a decoded JSON string before.

To give an example of the desired PHP output, for the first IP address (152.62.311.2:123) it should output:

> 8003
>   /Main:5.1/
>   1655659260
>   1
>   395047
>   ec4.ap-southeast-3.amazonaws.com
>   Capetown
>   AU
>   -317.8815
>   57.5
>   Australia/NSW
>   AS1511
>   Amazon.com, Inc

Comment: Also, I'd like it to output the IP address itself of "152.62.311.2:123" before outputting all the 13 pieces of sub-information about it.

Comment: Op, then edit your question instead of commenting.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't the best solution possible, but it is a solution...

```
$decoded = json_decode($json);
$ipInfo= $decoded[0][0]->jobs->{'152.62.311.2:123'};
print_r($ipInfo);
```

The jobs array outputs as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8003
    [1] => /Main:5.1/
    [2] => 1655659260
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 395047
    [5] => ec4.ap-southeast-3.amazonaws.com
    [6] => Capetown
    [7] => AU
    [8] => -317.8815
    [9] => 57.5
    [10] => Australia/NSW
    [11] => AS1511
    [12] => Amazon.com, Inc.
)
```

You can see an example here: https://ideone.com/bzhhLI

If you purely wanted to loop through and print out all the information you could do this, although it's not a very pretty solution:

```
$json = '[
    [{
        "timestamp": 1456815458,
        "total_jobs": 6398,
        "latest_height": 99045,
        "jobs": {
            "152.62.311.2:123": [8003, "/Main:5.1/", 1655659260, 1, 395047, "ec4.ap-southeast-3.amazonaws.com", "Capetown", "AU", -317.8815, 57.5, "Australia/NSW", "AS1511", "Amazon.com, Inc."],
            "183.215.34.58:9805": [56734, "/JobPlace2:0.11.0/", 1455767214, 1, 399047, "185.211.134.58", "Seoul", "KR", 57.5983, 126.9783, "Asia/Seoul", "AS32665", "HCLC"]
        }
    }]
]';




$decoded = json_decode($json);
$jobs = $decoded[0][0]->jobs->{'152.62.311.2:123'};

header('content-type: text/plain');
foreach ($decoded[0][0]->jobs as $ip => $ipData) {
    echo $ip . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($ipData as $data) {
        echo $data . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And now all that's left is how do I get the IP address in the first place? I tried doing something like this but it didn't work:
echo $json_feed[0]->{'jobs'}[0];

Comment: @C.H. Unfortunatly since the array key is the IP address itself, you can't access it with 'jobs'[0]. I've updated my post with a way you could loop through all the data and print it all out, but my brains slowly melting today so the solution isn't very pretty ;_;

Comment: Yes, I do want to loop through and print all the information. That last part loops through and answers my question. Thank you! If there's a prettier way and your brain un-melts, feel free to share. But at least I have something that works now.

Comment: Glad it helps, no doubt someone smarter than me will come along and have a pretty solution at some point, if not I'll probably have another look tomorrow after a good nights sleep. ^^

Comment: Ok sounds great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Pigeon answered this. Here is the concise answer that works beautifully:

```
$json_data = '[[{"timestamp": 1456815458,"total_jobs": 6398,"latest_height": 99045,"jobs": {"152.62.311.2:123": [8003,"/Main:5.1/", 1655659260, 1, 395047, "ec4.ap-southeast-3.amazonaws.com", "Capetown", "AU", -317.8815, 57.5, "Australia/NSW", "AS1511", "Amazon.com, Inc."],"183.215.34.58:9805": [56734, "/JobPlace2:0.11.0/", 1455767214, 1, 399047, "185.211.134.58", "Seoul", "KR", 57.5983, 126.9783, "Asia/Seoul", "AS32665", "HCLC"]}}]]';

$json_feed = json_decode($json_data);

foreach ($json_feed[0]->jobs as $ip => $ipData) {
    echo "<br><b>IP Address: ". $ip . "</b><br>";
    foreach ($ipData as $data) {
        echo "Data: ". $data . "<br>";
    }
}
```